# ¿Cómo concatenar dos listas de distintas clases?

Tags: c#, .net

Estoy intentando concatenar dos listas de distintas clases, para que me entiendan les pongo un ejemplo:

Tengo dos clases llamados `Alumno` y `Profesor`

```
class Alumno
{
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

class Profesor
{
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Telefono { get; set; }
}
```

Y también tengo dos listas para estas dos clases:

```
List<Alumno> Alumnos = new List<Alumno>();
List<Profesor> Profesores = new List<Profesor>();
```

Lo que busco es concatenar estas dos listas en una sola para poder ordenar todos los alumnos y profesores por su `Id` y poder imprimir todos sus datos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como cada lista no comparte misma información (y podría ser hasta tipo), se tiene que buscar que el consolidado entre ambos sean iguales, para ello sería necesario crear clases anónimas entre ambas para emparejarlas.

Por ejemplo:

```
List<Alumno> alumnos = new List<Alumno>() {
    new Alumno { Nombre = "A", Id = 1, Email = "D" } 
};

List<Profesor> profesores = new List<Profesor>() { 
    new Profesor { Nombre = "B", Id = 2, Telefono = "E" } 
};

var anonimoAlumnos = alumnos
    .Select(a => new { 
        a.Nombre, 
        a.Id, 
        Adicional = a.Email, 
        Tipo = a.GetType().ToString() 
    });

var anonimoProfesores = profesores
    .Select(a => new { 
        a.Nombre, 
        a.Id, 
        Adicional = a.Telefono, 
        Tipo = a.GetType().ToString() 
    });
```

Luego, se genera un consolidado con el método extendido `Concat`.

```
var concatenadoAnonimos = anonimoAlumnos.Concat(anonimoProfesores);

foreach(var anonimo in concatenadoAnonimos){
    Console.WriteLine("Nombre = {0}, Id = {1}, Adicional = {2}, Tipo = {3}", anonimo.Nombre, anonimo.Id, anonimo.Adicional, anonimo.Tipo);
}
```

Obtendrías:

> ```
> Nombre = A, Id = 1, Adicional = D, Tipo = Alumno
> Nombre = B, Id = 2, Adicional = E, Tipo = Profesor
> ```

[**DEMO**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aPF0T3)

---

**Referencia:**

- [Método Queryable.Concat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb351755(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Ya que ambas clases no son parte de una jerarquía de clases en común (excepto claro está en la clase base `Object`) no conviene concatenarlos sin antes proyectarlos hacia una clase en común (que puede ser anónima) para poder luego ordenarlos por `Id`
Ejemplo

```
var lista = Alumnos
    .Select(a => new { a.Nombre, a.Id, a.Email, Telefono = default(string) })
    .Concat(Profesores.
            Select(p => new { p.Nombre, p.Id, Email = default(string), p.Telefono }))
    .OrderBy(x=> x.Id);
```

Luego de esto ya puedes recorrerlo

```
foreach(var x in lista)
{
    ...  // x tiene las propiedades de Alumnos y Profesores
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear un diccionario de objetos para que tengas ambas listas en una sola.

```
var respuesta = new Dictionary<string, object>();                    
respuesta.Add("alumno ", alumno );
respuesta.Add("profesor ", profesor );
```

Comment: He probado la propiedad Concat pero me da un error al utilizarla, me dice lo siguiente "List<Alumnos> no contiene una definición para `Concat`", sabes a que se debe?

Comment: Es porque alumnos y profesores no son del mismo tipo. Creare otra respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

**Buen día**

Prueba usando ArrayList (es sugerencia no lo he hecho); llenalo con los contenidos de los 2 List; si lo soporta entonces algo como lo siguiente:

```
ArrayList lista = new ArrayList();
lista.AddRange(Alumnos);
lista.AddRange(Profesores);

lista = lista.OrderBy(o => (o.GetType()==Alumnos?((Alumnos)o).Id: ((Profesores)o).Id).ToArray();
```

Si le quieres  ordenar por nombre pues antes del `ToArray()` pones el `ThenBy` y similar al `OrderBy` pero en lugar de Id (por ejmplo) usas el `Nombre`.

Si lo anterior falla y/o no funciona ( :D ) entonces **Plan B**:

```
class ParaOrdenar
{
    public string Nombre { get { return alumno==null?profesor.Nombre:alumno.Nombre;  } }
    public int Id { get { return alumno==null?profesor.Id:alumno.Id;  } }
    public Alumno alumno { get; set; }
    public Profesor profesor { get; set; }

    public ParaOrdenar() {
        // solo uno de los dos no será null
        alumno=null;
        profesor=null;
    }

}
```

Llenamos:

```
List<ParaOrdenar> lista = new List<ParaOrdenar>();

foreach(Alumno alm in Alumnos)
{
   ParaOrdenar nuevo = new ParaOrdenar();
   nuevo.alumno=alm;
   lista.Add(nuevo);
}
// Lo mismo anterior con Profesores pero a "nuevo.profesor"

lista = lista.OrderBy(o => o.Id).ThenBy( t => t.Nombre).ToArray();
```

Espero te sirva